# Using Select for Multiple Socket Connections C

Tags: c, sockets, select, file-descriptor

I am trying to build a server and client for a chat server using sockets. I know that I am supposed to use select() to get input from multiple sockets, but I am not sure how to do it and still read from them properly. As my code sits, it reads perfectly fine from one client, but when two are open it ignores everything that the second client does, until the first is closed.

I am wondering how to properly implement select to make sure that I can take input from multiple sockets. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "../../include/my.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void interrupt();

void interrupt()
{
    my_str("Server exiting.\n");
    exit(0);
}

int str_to_num(char* str)      
{
        int i = 0;
        int numDigits = 0;
        int ret = 0;

        while (str[numDigits] != '\0')
        {
                numDigits++;
        }

        while (i < numDigits)
        {
                int digit = str[i];

                if (digit < 48 && digit > 57)
                        return -1;

                digit -= 48;

                ret += digit * my_pow(10, numDigits - i - 1);
                i++;
        }

        return ret;
}

char* add_null_term(char* str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
        i++;

    str[i] = '\0';

    return str;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portnum;
    int len;
    char buffer[256];
    /*char *username = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));*/
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    /*check args*/
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        my_str("Usage: ./server <port_number>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    portnum = str_to_num(argv[1]);

    if (portnum < 1024)
    {
        perror("Ports below 1024 are reserved for root access.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (portnum < 1 || portnum > 65535)
    {
        my_str("Port must be between 1 and 65535\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    signal(SIGINT, interrupt);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(0);
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1)
    {
        if ((newsockfd=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen)) < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(0);
        }

        usleep(2000);

        my_str("Server received: ");

        while ((len = read(newsockfd, &buffer, 256)) > 0)
        {
            buffer[my_strlen(buffer)] = '\0';

            if (my_strcmp(buffer, "/") == 0)
            {
                my_str("Error: command ");
                my_str(buffer);
                my_str("not found.\n");
                bzero((char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }

            /*if (count == 0)
            {
                my_strcpy(username, buffer);
                my_str("setting nickname to: ");
                my_str(username);
                bzero((char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                my_str(buffer);
                count++;
                my_str("\n");
            }*/

            /*else if (my_strncmp(buffer, "/me", 3) == 0)
            {
                my_str(username);
                my_str(" ");
                my_str(&buffer[4]);
                bzero((char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                my_str("\n");
            }

            else if (my_strncmp(buffer, "/nick", 5) == 0)
            {
                my_str("Changing nickname of ");
                my_str(username);
                my_strcpy(username, &buffer[6]);
                my_str(" to ");
                my_str(username);
                bzero((char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                my_str("\n");
            }*/

            /*else
            {*/
                /*my_str(username);
                my_str(": ");*/
                my_str(buffer);
                bzero((char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                my_str(buffer);
                my_str("\n");
            /*}*/
        }

        my_str("\nServer: Message end. Waiting for next connection.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried using select instead of accept in the first if statement, and of course added the fd_set and other needed bits. The server started, but it would not accept any input

Comment: You tried using select instead of accept? select and accept do different things. That would be like trying to use a hammer instead of a pair of headphones, and expecting to still hear music - it doesn't really make sense at all.

Comment: thanks that's quite helpful. Of course they do. I am trying to find out what to do to properly use select, instead of accept.

Comment: The code you have has several issues anyway - the ususal suspects.  Failure to correctly and completely handle the result returned by recv().  Failure to handle the octet streaming nature of TCP and the assumption that TCP can transfer, on its own, messages larger than one byte.  Misuse of strlen()-style calls on char buffers that are not guaranteed null-terminated.  Probably more:(

Comment: As for `select()`, it is used to determine which sockets *currently* have data available to read, and / or are prepared to accept data you write.  You use `select()` to multiplex multiple sockets, reading each when there's actually something to read, so that you do not block on one socket when there's data available from another.

Comment: As an alternative to `select()`, you might also be able to handle each connection in a separate thread or child process.  The I/O handling is easier in these approaches, but they have their own challenges.

Comment: `if (digit < 48 && digit > 57)` There is very little chance that this condition will ever be true.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is HOW to use select() in a server... 
Here is a snippet off the top of my head of one technique 
to get you started... bear in mind all error checking is not
present, and it is not optimized to function in a round robin 
basis...

```
listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN)

fd_set my_set;
fd_set wk_set;

FD_ZERO(&my_set);         /* initialize  fd_set */
FD_SET(sock_fd, &my_set)  /* put listener into fd_set */
max_fd = sockfd;

while( TRUE )
{
    memcpy(&wk_set, &my_set, sizeof(my_set));

    rc = select(max_fd + 1, &wk_set, NULL, NULL, NULL )
    if ( rc == -1 )
    {
        if ( errno == EINTR )
            continue;
        printf("select failed: errno = %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < max_fd; i++) /* check everything in wk_set */
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET(i, &wk_set)
        {
            if ( i == sockfd )  /* is it the listener socket?? */
            {
                wk_sock=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
                if ( wk_sock == -1 )
                {
                    printf("accept failed: errno=%d\n", errno);
                    exit(1);
                }
                FD_SET(wk_sock, &my_set);  /* put into fd_set */
                if ( wk_sock > max_sock )
                    max_sock = wk_sock;
            }else{
                /* ready to read from this socket */
                recv_len = recv(i, .... )
                if ( recv_len == 0 ) /* client disconnected */
                {
                    close(i);
                    FD_CLR(i, &my_set);
                    if (i == max_fd )
                    {
                        for(x=0;x<max_fd;x++)  /* find new max_fd */
                        {
                            if ( FD_ISSET(x, &my_set )
                                max_fd = x;
                        }
                    }
                } else { 
                handle message from client
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```